# Installing windowsxp alongside dual boot system already having ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

I already have a dual boot system with a grub boot loader.

I want to install a windowsxp os.

How do I modify grub boot loader after installing windows xp in a partition.... So that grub includes options to boot from all 3 os.

Ubuntu - /Dev/sda7
Windows7 /Dev/sda2

Also when I checked Gparted I saw that there is /Dev/sda4 "extended" that is the sum of /dev/sda5 /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7. Is there any concern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

shrink your biggest partition so there is at least 8 GB space for windows XP. The insert the reinstall disc of winXP and when it asks you which partition select the empty one(better remeber how big it was.) it should install. Also do quick format as FAT32. This will actually make the ubuntu system not run fsck. it really should work. Then once XP is running, get a package of the net called grub4dos. This should update grub. And there u go! And no, partition there is no concern if it shows that for an extended partition.